# have problem in telnet client server with python

Tags: python, sockets, server, telnet

i want to make telnet server in python.

here is my server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

SK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = "192.168.1.10"
PORT = 23

SK.bind((HOST, PORT))
SK.listen(5)

(Attacker_connection, (Attacker_IP, Attacker_PORT)) = SK.accept()

while True:
    Command = Attacker_connection.recv(4096)
    Command = Command.decode("ascii")
    if Command == "Quit":
        break
```

and the client test command:

> telnet 192.168.1.10

But the server error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Telnet_H.py", line 18, in <module>
    Command = Command.decode("ascii")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

client error:

```
Trying 192.168.1.10...
Connected to 192.168.1.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

why that's happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: `0xff` is the code of IAC, which indicates the start of a TELNET command. Please refer to [RFC 854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) for protocol details and implement the protocol accordingly.